# String matching algorithm trying to correct it

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to do string matching algorithm a brute force method. but The algorithm is not working correctly, I get an out of bound index error.

here is my algorithm

```
int main() {

 string s = "NOBODY_NOTICED_HIM";
 string pattern="NOT";

 int index = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < s.size();)
 {
    for (int j = 0; j < pattern.size();)
    {
        if(s[index] == pattern[j])
        {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            index = i;
                    j = 0;

        }
    }
 }
 cout<<index<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

FIXED VERSION

I fixed the out of bound exception. I don't know if the algorithm will work with different strings

```
int main() {

 string s = "NOBODY_NOTICED_HIM";
 string pattern="NOT";

 int index = 0;
 int i = 0;
 while( i < s.size())
 {
    i++;
    for (int j = 0; j < pattern.size();)
    {
        if(s[index] == pattern[j])
        {
            index++;
            j++;

            cout<<"i is " <<i << " j is "<<j <<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            index = i;

            break;
        }
    }
 }
 cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I don't have a debugger right now. I'm using ideone for testing

Comment: There's still that _How to debug small programs_ proposal.

Comment: Your first loop should only go as far as `s.size() - pattern.size()`, for a start. However, it will still be broken; use `printf`/`cout` to see what is happening.

Comment: If you have no debugger, next time you see an out of bound error, you try to estimate where it might happen (obviously somewhere where you access an array-like structure) and at least do some system output that gives you the desired position and the size, like cout << "pos is " << j << " size is " << pattern.size() << endl; Btw, the regular string matching problem usually wants ALL valid shifts, not just one as you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the inner for loop has a condition to loop while `j` is less than `pattern.size()` but you are also incrementing `i` inside the body. When `i` goes out of bounds of `s.size()` then `index` also goes out of bounds and you'd get an OutOfBounds error.

The brute force method has to test the pattern with every possible subsequence. The main condition is the length, which has to be the same. All subsequence from s are:

> ['NOB', 'OBO', 'BOD', 'ODY', 'DY_', 'Y_N', '*NO', 'NOT', 'OTI', 'TIC',
>   'ICE', 'CED', 'ED*', 'D_H', '_HI', 'HIM']

There are many ways to do it, you can do it char by char, or by using string operations like taking a substring. Both are nice excercises for learning.

Starting at zero in the s string you take the first three chars, compare to the pattern, and if equal you give the answer. Otherwise you move on to the char starting at one, etc.

Comment: here is the fix, but I don't know if the algorithm should be correct or not.
https://ideone.com/n0F3N3

Comment: I added a fixed version, which resolves the out of boundary. but I don't know if the algorithm is correct or not

Comment: No, you did not, you still have an out of bounds error. Recompile your program with _GLIBCXX_DEBUG macro, you can #define _GLIBCXX_DEBUG 1 as the first line of your .cpp file.

Comment: Change your string from ..._HIM to ..._HIN